# javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]

Tags: email, notifications, smtp, weblogic

Im having problems with sending out a notification through SMTP using either smtp.gmail.com or smtp-relay.gmail.com. Here is the error thats been given

Note: Im using Oracle Weblogic Server for the SMTP Notification.

```
<BEA-320047> <Mail notification has not been sent due to an error that occurred while creating or sending a mail message:
com.bea.diagnostics.notifications.NotificationPropagationException: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
        at com.bea.diagnostics.notifications.SMTPNotificationService.send(SMTPNotificationService.java:253)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.SMTPNotificationListener.processWatchNotification(SMTPNotificationListener.java:218)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.Watch.performNotifications(Watch.java:608)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.Watch.evaluateLogRuleWatch(Watch.java:532)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.WatchManager.evaluateLogEventRulesAsync(WatchManager.java:752)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.WatchManager.run(WatchManager.java:512)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1481)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1512)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
        at com.bea.diagnostics.notifications.SMTPNotificationService.send(SMTPNotificationService.java:235)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.SMTPNotificationListener.processWatchNotification(SMTPNotificationListener.java:218)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.Watch.performNotifications(Watch.java:608)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.Watch.evaluateLogRuleWatch(Watch.java:532)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.WatchManager.evaluateLogEventRulesAsync(WatchManager.java:752)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.watch.WatchManager.run(WatchManager.java:512)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I don't have a clue on how i can resolve it and i do have a deadline by friday :( Badly needed help with this one. Thanks in advance guys.